# Can I still play LoL even if I switched country?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am from Canada, so my account is ATM in the NA server but in a few days, i'm moving to Singapore. With this big move, Will I still be able to play on the NA and will there be any consequences of playing outside of Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When creating an account, player must choose a server on which wants to play (usually the one whose server belongs their country). Once created, this belongs solely to the server in which was created, and the login credentials are not valid for other servers.
>
> In order to play with the account in another server, that is, to transfer it to another server, transfer can be purchased in Riot Store of the PvP.net client, on the tab "Account".
>
> Generally, transfers to another server costs RP 2600. RU, TR, BR, LAN and LAS servers does not have the possibility of transfer to some servers. Currently, is not possible to transfer from or to servers SEA and KR, the first one because the server is hosted by 3rd party Garena, and the later one due to be available only to users in South Korea.

You actually HAVE to continue playing on the NA server if you don't make a new account, <s>unless you buy a transfer</s>. EDIT: Just realised, three years later, that Singapore is part of the SEA group of servers and so is run by Garena, meaning accounts from other servers can't be transferred at all.

Playing on a server a great distance from you will have much higher latency and will cause "lag".

Comment: Thanks a lot! By any chance know how bad the lag will be and if it's going go be every game?

Comment: http://www.verizonenterprise.com/about/network/latency/

Verizon lists "Signapore to US" pings with an average latency of around 180 ms. For a game of League, that's pretty high, but not unplayable.

Comment: And yeah, it'll basically be every game. The networking distance between Singapore and the US is so high, you'll never see less than 150ms ping. On bad days with lots of traffic and server load, you can also expect to go above 200ms. It'll vary greatly, some days will be better than others, but you'll never get the same kind of low latency that you would from just playing on a native server.

Comment: @DunkDarius This is of course depending on your internet connection (VDSL vs ADSL). From my experience (Playing on EU from NA) it is playable with a ping of around 90, just to give you a raw estimation. A Internet connection with 30Mbps assumed.